# is_user_logged_in() always returns false for woocommerce_login_redirect

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to redirect active subscribers to the shop page. I use `woocommerce_login_redirect` with 999 priority in a plugin, so this functions.php code is supposed to override the target page if the user is an active subscriber.

```
function has_active_subscription( $user_id='' ) {
    // When a $user_id is not specified, get the current user Id        
    if( '' == $user_id && is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // User not logged in we return false
    if( $user_id == 0 ) 
        return false;

    return wcs_user_has_subscription( $user_id, '', 'active' );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'active_subscriber_user_redirect', 1000, 2 );
function active_subscriber_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    if ( has_active_subscription() ) {
        $shop_page_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
        $redirect = $shop_page_url;
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

To help to troubleshoot, I successfully redirected via `woocommerce_login_redirect` when `$redirect` was hardcoded as the shop page to make sure that the issue lies within `has_active_subscription` function.

Then I tried `if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return true;` as the 1st line of `has_active_subscription` function - it returns false what is the direct reason why this entire logic doesn't work as supposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this based on a user logging in, you can't use `is_user_logged_in()`.

When a redirect filter runs, it is based on what is occurring when a login is being processed - that's true for WP's general hook and for WC's. The user is not actually seen as logged in until after the redirect occurs.

`woocommerce_login_redirect` has the same parameters as WP's `login_redirect` - the `$redirect` value being filtered (since it's a filter), and `$user`, which is the user object of the user logging in.  You need to get the user ID from the `$user` object.

Dump your `has_active_subscription()` for this - it is not needed - and just pass the user ID from the `$user` object.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'active_subscriber_user_redirect', 1000, 2 );
function active_subscriber_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    if ( wcs_user_has_subscription( $user->ID, '', 'active' ) ) {
        $shop_page_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
        $redirect = $shop_page_url;
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

*Note: some might consider this off-topic as it relates to WooCommerce (a third party plugin). However, IMO, it hits some important elements about WordPress and login state, as well as the fact that `login_redirect` and `woocommerce_login_redirect` operate in essentially the same way, so this answer applies to `login_redirect` as well.

Comment: I checked `wcs_user_has_subscription` and actually `$user->ID` can be replaced with an empty value because another function will get ID of current user if not specified.

Comment: That's only *if* the current user is set, which it's not when the login redirect filter is triggered. It's the same reason `is_user_logged_in()` was returning false for you. If you dig into `is_user_logged_in()`, you'll see that it ultimately relies on the private function `_wp_get_current_user()`, which sets the current user ID as "0" if the current user is null (i.e. not logged in).